# Aligning QMenuBar items (add some on left and some on right side)

Tags: qt, cross-platform, qmenu

Currently I have QMenuBar with three QActions and it looks like this:

[image]

but I would like to get this (get some QActions right-aligned):

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one possible solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575687/how-do-i-set-qmenu-to-align-to-the-right-of-a-toolbar). But it involves implementing your own style (QStyle as I recall). However here is a snippet that I have just tried on mainwindow class:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)  {  

ui->setupUi(this);

QMenuBar *barLeft = new QMenuBar; 
QMenuBar *barRight = new QMenuBar;

barLeft->addAction("Foo Left 1");
barLeft->addAction("Foo Left 2");
barRight->addAction("Foo Left 1");
barRight->addAction("Foo Left 2");

QHBoxLayout *mainMenuLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

mainMenuLayout->addWidget(barLeft);
mainMenuLayout->addWidget(barRight);

mainMenuLayout->setAlignment(barLeft, Qt::AlignLeft);
mainMenuLayout->setAlignment(barRight, Qt::AlignRight);

QWidget *central = new QWidget;
central->setLayout(mainMenuLayout);

setCentralWidget(central);
```

}

This should be suitable.

Answer (score 18):

Probably the most simple solution to this particular problem is to use the corner widget. It can be used to place almost anything at the rightmost position, of course also a new menu bar:

```
QMenuBar *bar = new QMenuBar(ui->menuBar);

QMenu *menu = new QMenu("Test menu", bar);
bar->addMenu(menu);

QAction *action = new QAction("Test action", bar);
bar->addAction(action);

ui->menuBar->setCornerWidget(bar);
```

Result:

[image: Standard QMenuBar with additional rightmost 2nd QMenuBar]

This is esp. helpful when the main menu is still to be edited in QDesigner...

Comment: This is a better answer than the chosen answer imo.