# Align QMenuBar in Python

Tags: python, qt, alignment, pyqt4, qmenubar

I have to align 'Menu5' to the right side of MenuBar.
Is that possible in Python? (PyQt4)

[Example](http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/u1/k8/pq/hv517q.jpg)

I found information on how to do this in C there

> [Aligning QMenuBar items (add some on left and some on right side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726677/aligning-qmenubar-items-add-some-on-left-and-some-on-right-side)

But I don't know how I can do this in Python.

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()


        panel = QtGui.QWidget()
        panel.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(panel)
        menubar1 = self.menuBar()
        menubar1.addMenu('&Menu1')
        menubar1.addMenu('&Menu2')
        menubar1.addMenu('&Menu3')
        menubar1.addMenu('&Menu4')
        menubar1.addMenu('&Menu5')
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.move(300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('TestApp')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using QtDesigner? It makes GUI design much easier.

Comment: I tried but I had problem with this anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMenuBar has **setCornerWidget** function which allows you to do that.

```
    menubar1 = self.menuBar()
    menubar1.addMenu('&Menu1')
    menubar1.addMenu('&Menu2')
    menubar1.addMenu('&Menu3')
    menubar1.addMenu('&Menu4')

    self.menuBr= QtGui.QMenuBar(menubar1)
    menubar1.setCornerWidget(self.menuBr, QtCore.Qt.TopRightCorner)
    self.menu5 = QtGui.QMenu(self.menuBr)
    self.menu5.setTitle("Menu5")
    self.menuBr.addAction(self.menu5.menuAction())
```