# How can I move a QMenu item to the right corner of a QMenuBar

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

My menu items were added through the UI designer. I can't seem to find a proper solution. I've asked on IRC and this solution [How do I set QMenu to align to the right of a toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575687/how-do-i-set-qmenu-to-align-to-the-right-of-a-toolbar) was not clear to me.

Is there a simple way to do this by accessing the UI code in the MainWindow constructor? Or any other pointers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set QMenu to align to the right of a toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575687/how-do-i-set-qmenu-to-align-to-the-right-of-a-toolbar)

Answer (score 3):

To add a menu to the right side of menu bar, you can add a new `QMenuBar` containing the desired menu as the right corner widget using `setCornerWidget` :

```
QMenuBar *bar = new QMenuBar(ui->menuBar);

QMenu *menuHelp = new QMenu("Help", bar);
bar->addMenu(menuHelp);

ui->menuBar->setCornerWidget(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use QtDesigner, there's a "Property Editor" which lists all property of your current selected item.

If you select a menubar, there is one "layoutDirection" property, choose "LeftToRight" or "RightToLeft"

[image]

If you are manually set it. Just using like this:

```
 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 app.setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

Comment: This put all of my menu items on the right side. I need only my "About" menu item to be on the right....